# Use public functions inside a public function

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to use public functions inside a public function in php?

I got a few public functions which change the input and return it. I want to make a for statement inside a public function that loops through my functions, like:

```
$input

for= function1 -> output1 -> function2->output2->function3->output3.
```

I want to use the output of that for my next function. Also the 4 functions I have in my for loop has to loop 9 times.

in this case its about AES encrypt. i got 4 functions called: subBytes, shiftRows, mixColumns, addRoundkey.

This is my public function encrypt:

```
public function encrypt($input)
{
    $functions= ('subBytes', 'shiftRows', 'mixColumns', 'addRoundKey' );
    foreach($functions as $function)
    {
        $input = $$function($input);
    }

    return($input);
} //end function encrypt
```

and this is one of my functions:

```
public function subBytes($state)
{
    for ($row=0; $row<4; $row++){ // for all 16 bytes in the (4x4-byte) State
        for ($column=0; $column<4; $column++){ // for all 16 bytes in the (4x4-byte) State
            $_SESSION['debug'] .= "state[$row][$column]=" . $state[$row][$column] ."-->" . self::$sBox[$state[$row][$column]]."\n";
            $state[$row][$column] = self::$sBox[$state[$row][$column]];
        }
     }
     return $state;
}
```

Comment: `public function blabla()` means a method of a class. As long as it is not a `static` method it needs to be invoked using an object. You cannot call it just `subBytes()`, you probably want `$this->subBytes()`. When the function name is generated at runtime you can either use the solution presented in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35886758/4265352) or, for more complex situations (dynamic lists or arguments, f.e.) you can use the function [`call_user_func()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) using `array($this, $function)` as its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
$output3 = function3(function2(function1($input)));
```

Or you can to add your function name into array and iterate over it:

```
$input = ''; // some value
$functioins = ('function1', 'function2', 'function3', 'function4');
foreach ($functions as $function) {
    $input = $$function($input);
}
$output = $input;
```

If we try to use public functions of object then:

```
public function encrypt($input)
{
    // array with methods names
    $methods= array('subBytes', 'shiftRows', 'mixColumns', 'addRoundKey' );
    foreach($methods as $method)
    {
        $input = $this->$method($input);
    }

    return($input);
}
```

Comment: And how it influences on creation of function pipeline? You can with this method connects output of each previous function with input of succeeding function. Ok, I take a look on updated question

Comment: Try second version for public functions of object

Comment: i get the following error when i implemented your code:
parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\wamp\www\aes.php on line 114 something in the $methods line is not correct.

Comment: add into comment your 114 line, because error on that string, also this code for `public function encrypt` has no syntax errors at all

Comment: @Joostd the error propagated from the code you posted in the question. It should read `$methods = array('subBytes', ...);`. Or, if you prefer the short arrays notation `$methods = ['subBytes', ...];` i.e. use square brackets (`[` and `]`).

Comment: $methods= ('subBytes', 'shiftRows', 'mixColumns', 'addRoundKey' );

Comment: sorry:) i write code in text editor so no error highlights:)

Comment: still getting allot of errors :/ can i send you the whole code in some way? really frustrating that it doesnt work

Comment: let's try to fix errors one by one:) add next error into comment

Comment: well, its a whole page filled with errors, the code is pretty advanced, including a include_once to another php file.. first error is: Notice: Undefined variable: state in C:\wamp\www\aes.php on line 117

line 117: $input = $this->$method($state); i changed $method($input) to $state because all my functions work with $state.

edit: some functions have multiple variables, im getting alot of errors about that, i dont think this method wil work then.

Comment: if you change calling function `$this->$method($method);` to `$this->$method($state);` you also need to change signature to `public function encrypt($state)`

Comment: ive changed the array for now, to only the first step: subBytes.. this one works! i get an output, now i need to use that output for my next functions..

`public function encrypt($input)
    {
        // array with methods names
        $methods= array('subBytes'/*, 'shiftRows', 'mixColumns', 'addRoundKey' */);
        foreach($methods as $method)
        {
            $input = $this->$method($input);
        }

        return($input);`

Comment: How your progress in the implementation of the full encrypt code?

Comment: got 3 out of 4 functions running, my last function has multiple variables. that one doesnt work.
public function addRoundKey($state, $w, $rnd).
Missing argument 2 for Aes::addRoundKey()

`$subBytes = 'subBytes';
        $shiftRows = 'shiftRows';
        $mixColumns = 'mixColumns';
        $addRoundkey = 'addRoundKey';
        for ($k = 1; $k <= 1; $k++)
        {
            $input = $this->$subBytes($input);
            $input = $this->$shiftRows($input);
            $input = $this->$mixColumns($input);
            $input = $this->$addRoundkey($input);
        }`

Comment: Where do we need to get `$w`, `$rnd` from?

Comment: $w is generated in a different public static function.$rnd is only mentioned in addRoundkey

Comment: You need to pass them to your fourth function, so you need to get it somewhere before this `foreach` cycle. Is this params available before starting `foreach` cyecle?

Comment: i used it like this now:  $input = `$this->$addRoundkey($input, $w, $rnd);`
I get no errors now, but the function isn't correct now so im guessing one of those two variables are not filled correctly.